# Создание темы для wordpress из html шаблона

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Возникли некоторые сложности с созданием темы для Wordpress, если по точнее, с натяжкой готового html шаблона. Скачал html шаблон http://html5up.net/striped и стартовую тему underscores.me. В шаблоне есть папка assets в которой кроме папок со скриптами и стилями есть еще две папки, это fonts и sass.
Так вот, для чего эти две папки нужны? Я не нашел в индексном шаблоне какую нибудь ссылку или тег который указывал бы на эти файлы.

Comment: Вопросы стоит задавать по одному. Третий вопрос скорее всего будет оффтоп, ищите в сторону *wordpress theme customizer*. И лучше начинать читать на английском, например, [здесь](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)

Comment: Я думал, если вопросы по одной теме, то их можно так задать. Мне сейчас что делать, разбить на части этот вопрос и вывести каждую часть по отдельности? С английским не очень, русскоязычное руководство скиньте пожалуйста.

Comment: Кастомизировать тему можно двумя способами: [создать дочернюю тему](http://janiwanow.com/blog/theme-customizer-in-wordpress/) или [кастомизировать текущую](http://janiwanow.com/blog/theme-customizer-in-wordpress/). С первым не работал, т.к. пока делали только свои, вроде как вам нужен он (хотя и не уверен, т.к. не работал с этим). А второй вариант, наверно, больше подходит только для своих тем

Comment: Как я понял мне лучше будет разбить этот вопрос на несколько. Первый, оставить этот вопрос с первым абзацем. Второй, например "Применение своих стилей к виджетам WordPress". И третий,  "Возможность настройки темы в админки". Так?

Comment: На счет второго вопроса. С шаблоном в комплекте идут файлы стилей, и вот в этих файлах прописано как должны отображаться некоторые виджеты(поиск, текстовое поле, последние записи и комментарии и календарь). При добавлении виджета через админку в сайдбар к эти виджетам не применяются никакие стили, т.е. они выводятся так как прописано в WordPress. Как сделать чтобы при добавлении виджета к нему применялись стили из шаблона html, чтобы они выводились так же как и в шаблоне. Про кастомизацию сейчас почитаю, вдруг найду там ответы.

Comment: Английский и в правду надо начинать изучать, только ведь это дело не одного дня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fonts** - папка для шрифтов, ее использует файл font-awesome.min.css:

```
@font-face{
font-family:'FontAwesome';
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format('woff2'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal
}
```

и т.п. далее по файлу

**sass** - учитывая расположение и расширение файлов в данной папке, она может использоваться для препроцессора [sass](http://sass-scss.ru/documentation/sintaksis/)

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а файл font-awesome.min.css как подключают к шаблону html? В папке css есть два файла font-awesome.min.css и  main.css. Файл main.css вот так подключен:<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" /> Подключение font-awesome.min.css  не нашел.
 Если sass нигде не используется зачем она там лежит? Можно ли ее удалить?

Comment: @MrBlack файл main.css - `@import url("font-awesome.min.css");`

Comment: Блин, это же самая первая строчка) Извините, не заметил.

Comment: @MrBlack отредактировали ответ, предположительно папка **sass** используется для препроцессора sass. если Вы его не используете, то можете удалить папку.

Comment: Возможно вопрос покажется глупым, но я его все таки задам. Как узнать используется sass или нет? Где должно быть подключение к файлам папки sass?

Comment: В папке sass файлы с расширением " .scss". Как эти файлы подключаются к шаблону html?

Comment: @MrBlack если Вы не используете sass, то никак, в противном случае Вам нужно подключить их вручную. Формат .scss - это новый синтаксис SASS.

Comment: @MrBlack более подробная информация о синтаксисах( и расширениях в т.ч.) [здесь](http://sass-scss.ru/documentation/sintaksis/).

Comment: @ Alex, спасибо за Вашу помощь.